# Unix: Xargs won't terminate

Tags: shell, unix, xargs

I've read through the man pages for xargs a dozen times and I still can't figure out how to get it to terminate.  When I call this at the shell: `xargs echo this is xargs`
I only see output when I press ctrl+d. Isn't there a way to specify that I want xargs to stop after reading a certain number of arguments? So that when I type `xargs echo this is xargs` and press enter I immediately see `this is xargs` without having to press ctrl+d?

I have tried setting the eof flag with -e and -E and neither worked for me when doing so like this:

`xargs -Ez echo this is xargs z`

I'm asking because I'm trying to write a C program that forks a child and uses execl to call xargs, but my program hangs, so before I try to continue coding the program I want to at least be able to call xargs just right from the command line.

Comment: you have to feed data into `xargs` via a pipe.`echo this is xargs| xargs echo` might work. A more sample invocation that uses xargs in a idomatic way might be `find . -print | xargs stat` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xargs **executes utility/command once it got the input from standard input file**.

When you are trying executing xargs `echo something something` its waiting for the input from the standard input file, once you pressed **<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>** which means EOF, Xargs execute the command with the arguments from the standard input file.

Below are the examples.

```
bash-$ echo "Testing xargs command" | xargs echo 
# echo executes by reading the input  
#file from pipe ( which redirects first commands output into second commands input )
Testing xargs command #output
bash-$ 
bash-$ 
bash-$ xargs echo #waits until CTRL+D is pressed
Testing xargs command
Testing xargs command  #output
bash-$ 
bash-$ 
bash-$ xargs -E EOF echo # xargs option -E specifies End-OF-File-String, here EOF
Testing xargs command
EOF
Testing xargs command #output
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` reads input from stdin which it then appends to the parameters you have passed to it. What you are seeing is that when you run `xargs` it is awaiting input from stdin (apparently hangs), when you type ctl+d - this is EOF to stdin therefore `xargs` processes all it has read.

An example of `xargs` to `grep` for the string "string" in all files named *.conf

```
find . -name \*.conf -print | xargs grep string
```